# Python/Django Concatenate a string depending on whether that string exists

Tags: python, django, string-concatenation

I'm creating a property on a Django model called "address". I want address to consist of the concatenation of a number of fields I have on my model. The problem is that not all instances of this model will have values for all of these fields. So, I want to concatenate only those fields that have values.

What is the best/most Pythonic way to do this?

Here are the relevant fields from the model:

```
house = models.IntegerField('House Number', null=True, blank=True)
suf = models.CharField('House Number Suffix', max_length=1, null=True, blank=True)
unit = models.CharField('Address Unit', max_length=7, null=True, blank=True)
stex = models.IntegerField('Address Extention', null=True, blank=True)
stdir = models.CharField('Street Direction', max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
stnam = models.CharField('Street Name', max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
stdes = models.CharField('Street Designation', max_length=3, null=True, blank=True)
stdessuf = models.CharField('Street Designation Suffix',max_length=1, null=True, blank=True)
```

I could just do something like this:

```
def _get_address(self):
    return "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s" % (self.house, self.suf, self.unit, self.stex, self.stdir, self.stname, self.stdes, self.stdessuf)
```

but then there would be extra blank spaces in the result.

I could do a series of if statements and concatenate within each, but that seems ugly.

What's the best way to handle this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
parts = (1, 'a', 'b', 2, 'c', 'd', None, 'f')
# parts = (self.house, self.suf, self.unit, 
#           self.stex, self.stdir, self.stname, 
#           self.stdes, self.stdessuf)
' '.join(str(part) for part in parts if part is not None)
# '1 a b 2 c d e f'
```

You just do a list comp, and check if any value is not None, and also convert them to a string so they join properly regardless of type.

Comment: Thanks for the 'not None' addition

Comment: @DouglasMeehan: Sure. Also if you want to save on creating a temp list every single time you call the method, you could save the fields in a list as a class attribute, since its not going to change between instances.

Comment: What's better in this situation? tuple or list?

Comment: So i would create another property which would be the list of these fields and then reference that property in the address property?

Comment: A list has a slight overhead over a tuple. But use a tuple since you aren't going to modify it at all. And ya you could create another class attribute at the bottom after the fields, then reference is in your method with `self._address_fields`

Comment: something like this?  def _get_address_fields(self):
        return [self.house, self.suf, self.unit, self.stex, self.stdir, self.stname, self.stdes, self.stdessuf]

    @property
    def address(self):
        return " ".join(str(s) for s in self._get_address_fields if s is not None)

Comment: @DouglasMeehan: I retract that extra suggestion. You would have to put it into the `__init__` to be efficient. Overall, its not really worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a generator to get just the non-Falsy values, and then join them. For example:

```
parts = (self.house, self.suf, self.unit, self.stex, self.stdir, self.stname, self.stdes, self.stdessuf)
return " ".join(str(s) for s in parts if s is not None)
```

Comment: You need to check for None, and not a Falsey value. None is not the same as 0 which is a valid number

Comment: so in that case, I could do 
parts = (self.house, self.suf, self.unit, self.stex, self.stdir, self.stname, self.stdes, self.stdessuf)
return " ".join(str(s) for s in parts if s is not None)?

Answer (score 2):

```
" ".join(filter(None, 
               [self.house, self.suf, self.unit, 
                self.stex, self.stdir, self.stname, 
                self.stdes, self.stdessuf]))
```

Comment: This breaks if the field is not a string.